# CSS HTML li item allways on the right/left, hide the rest

Tags: html, css, navbar

I have a nav bar wit several items.

```
<ul>
    <li class="fixedLeft"><a class="links-main" href="#">Left1</a></li>
    <li class="left"><a class="links-main" href="#">Left2</a></li>
    <li class="left"><a class="links-main" href="#">Left3</a></li>
    <li class="right"><a class="links-main" href="#">Right1</a></li>
    <li class="right"><a class="links-main" href="#">Right2</a></li>
    <li class="fixedRight"><a class="links-main" href="#">Right3</a></li>    
</ul>
```

I don't know how to fix the "fixedLeft" class to the left, and "fixedRight" class to the right, so that if i change the window size, or use it on a smaller window, those li are allways visible, the others are not important, if i can't see them i'll deal with that later.

(just to clear things up, i don't mean "float:left/right", i'm already using those.)

Right now when i change the size of the screen, the li start dissapearing right to left, **How can i avoid the "fixedRight" item to dissapear.**

(if possible, i'd like to implement the solution only with html and css)

Comment: Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself". Might as well read about creating a [mcve].

Comment: I guess you need @media queries

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way by using only pure CSS is with inline-block mode, like this example:

```
li {
  width: 80px;
  height: 20px;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  vertical-align: top;
  font-size: 0;
  position: relative;
  margin-right: -4px;
}

a {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul li:nth-child(1) {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 200;
  background-color: red;
}

ul li:nth-last-child(1) {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 200;
  background-color: red;
}

ul {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 80px;
  width: calc(100% - 160px);
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

Here is the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fabio1983/oc398jx9/